# Extracting the multiple line pattern SED or AWK

Tags: regex, sed, awk, grep, pcre

Hope the sed or awk gurus can help me out. I need to match a multiple line pattern in which the pattern range can span from one to three lines. I am not able to arrive at the result using pcregrep! The pattern I want to realise goes somewhat like this =>

```
\s*\w+\s\w+\([A-Za-z,]*\)\s*\;\{
```

The thing is that after the words or the semicolon, the following part of the pattern can or cannot occur in the next line AND the pattern can occur in a single line too, depending on the file.

Thanks in advance for the replies. I have been stuck at this step for almost a week! Any kind of suggestions appreciated :)

> Eg : apple orange(plum); kiwi {
>
> OR
>
> apple orange(plum);
>
> kiwi
>
> {

An expression to match both expressions.

Comment: What are you trying to match?

Comment: The syntax :[   word aphanumeric(Something);alphanumeric {    ]

The pattern doesnt necceserily occur in the same line but respects the specified syntax sequence. 
Thanks David for you reply.

Comment: It would be really helpful if you could post a sample of what you're matching against, and what you hope to extract out of it / match out of it. For example: `apple, I want to match all the p's`.

Comment: I have to extract the string :

Comment: David,I have edited the question with an example :) Hope you have got my explanation .I was not always good at explaining things :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\s*(\w+)\s+(\w+?)\((\w+)\);\s*(\w+)\s*{`

Yours was pretty close. Make sure you set the `MULTILINE` flag when you use the regex to ensure it matches across multiple lines. This will match all four words in your string. As per your example,

group 1: `apple`

group 2: `orange`

group 3: `plum`

group 4: `kiwi`

[You can play with the regex here](http://regexr.com?319mt).

Comment: Works likes a charm ! Thanks a lot.
I really appreciate it, man :)